# How to add button onto the GoogleMap

Tags: android

I'd like to add a button onto the GoogleMap displayed. My map is displayed as

```
GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

I use the fragment to display the map and the layout xml is

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

I found some info to load button onto the view, but theirs is just a normal view and not the GoogleMap.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a button directly into the Google Maps Object, so you have few options:

**1.** Overwrite the SupportMapFragment object with your own implementation and add the button to it.

**2.** The easy options is to set the `fragment` inside a `FrameLayout`, and add a button to this `FrameLayout` using a `LinearLayout` or directly, For example:

```
 <FrameLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLocateMe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/locate_me_button_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="locateMeButtonOnClick"
            android:text="@string/locate_me"
            android:textColor="@color/my_white" />
     </LinearLayout>
    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: That is the button and the map are loaded at the same time. Is it possible to load the button programatically, so that i can load it when it is time.

Comment: you can use the same layout and set the visibility of the button to invisible, then change it's visibility when you need. that way it will appear when you want to.

Comment: I load the map using map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();. How to load the whole layout?

Comment: Set this layout as the content view of you activity and then find the instance of the map from it.

Comment: I am new to Android. Can you pls show me the sample how to do that?

Comment: it's the most basic thing. call this layout: mapContainer and set it as setContentView(R.layout.mapContainer); the whole layout with your desired button included and then you can run this method:  map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: I glad you figured it out @Bryanyan, have a nice coding : )

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to place button on the map?

I have some solutions:

1. If you want static button you can place map fragment into RelativeView and place button in RelativeView.
2. Else if you want button, which will be moving along with map, you can place some shape on map eg.. circle by using addCircle method and use setOnMapClickListener to handle clicks on map. See [GoogleMap API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap)

Comment: If so, how can I display static text? Can I add a textview programatically? i just want to load the textview when it is necessary.

Comment: To do this you have to use a Paint object to create a bitmap of the text you want, then place a marker/ground overlay on the googlemap using that bitmap as the icon or image.